# Spark Sql: 'like' syntax error

Tags: apache-spark-sql

when I executed

`sqlcontext.sql("select * from logs where content like '%stream%' ")`

in my spark app ,error showed below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.39] failure: ``*'' expected but `%'
>   found
>
> select * from logs where content like %stream% 
>                                         ^
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.apply(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:40)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:130)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:130)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:96)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:95)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:890)
>           at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.apply(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$parseSql$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:134)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$parseSql$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:134)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:134)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:915)
>           at louis.spark.LogAnalysis$4.call(LogAnalysis.java:218)
>           at louis.spark.LogAnalysis$4.call(LogAnalysis.java:1)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:302)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:302)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:176)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:175)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How to use '`like`' syntax in spark sql ?  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using older version of spark, I have tested your query in Apache Spark 1.4.0, it's correct but according to the line ->

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.39] failure: ``*'' expected but `%' found
```

you should try this  ->

```
sqlcontext.sql("select * from logs where content like '*stream*' ")
```

Comment: I tried your way:

sqlcontext.sql("select * from logs where content like '*stream*' ")

the error below occured :

java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.40] failure: ``union'' expected but identifier level found

I'm using Apache Spark 1.3.0, is this version too old to work ?

Comment: sql_cmd="SELECT text_fld FROM PAYROLE WHERE NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', '"+text_to_search+"', '%')"
staff = spark.sql(sql_cmd)